# how to handle serialized data with WP_User_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I'm trying expand a custom user search in Wordpress; namely, I want to search the users by city, state and country, but these data are serialized.
My example
meta_key: `pie_address_3`;
 
meta_value: `a:6:{s:7:"address";s:18:"New York Street, 4";s:8:"address2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:5:"Venice";s:5:"state";s:7:"Vicenza";s:3:"zip";s:5:"36015";s:7:"country";s:5:"Italy";}`

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$my_users = new WP_User_Query(
      array( 
        'role' => $role,
        'search' => '*' . $search . '*',
        'search_columns' => array(
            'user_login',
            'user_nicename',
            'user_email',
            'user_url',
            'display_name'
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
              'key'     => 'pie_address_3',
              'value'   => $search,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
          )
      ));
```

But, when I type some country or city (which I know is associated with some user), the search result return nothing. How can I handle this? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have updated the `WP_User_Query` like this:

```
$args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'pie_address_3'
        );
        $query = new WP_User_Query($args);

        $authors = $query->get_results();

        foreach ($authors as $author){
            $c = get_user_meta($author->id,'pie_address_3',true);
            if(isset($c)){
                if(empty(get_user_meta($author->id,'address',true))){
                   add_user_meta($author->ID,'address',$c['address']); 
                }
                if(empty(get_user_meta($author->id,'address2',true))){
                   add_user_meta($author->ID,'address2',$c['address2']); 
                }
                if(empty(get_user_meta($author->id,'city',true))){
                   add_user_meta($author->ID,'city',$c['city']); 
                }
                if(empty(get_user_meta($author->id,'state',true))){
                   add_user_meta($author->ID,'state',$c['state']); 
                }
                if(empty(get_user_meta($author->id,'zip',true))){
                   add_user_meta($author->ID,'zip',$c['zip']); 
                }
                if(empty(get_user_meta($author->id,'country',true))){
                   add_user_meta($author->ID,'country',$c['country']); 
                };
                //delete_user_meta($author->ID,'pie_address_3',$c);
            }
        }

        $my_users = new WP_User_Query(
          array( 
            'role' => $role,
            'search' => '*' . $search . '*',
            'search_columns' => array(
                'user_login',
                'user_nicename',
                'user_email',
                'user_url',
                'display_name'
            ),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                  'key'     => 'address',
                  'value'   => $search,
                  'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                  'key'     => 'address2',
                  'value'   => $search,
                  'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                  'key'     => 'city',
                  'value'   => $search,
                  'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                  'key'     => 'state',
                  'value'   => $search,
                  'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                  'key'     => 'zip',
                  'value'   => $search,
                  'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                  'key'     => 'country',
                  'value'   => $search,
                  'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
              )
          )
        );
```

But still, it doesn't work. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated answer

I realized you needed to find the users that contain the string `$search` inside the `pie_address_3` field **OR** in at least one of the other columns.

Unfortunately `WP_User_Query` doesn't seem to allow that **OR** relation between columns and meta field. In fact the "conditional" part of the resultant query is something like this:

```
WHERE (
    user_login LIKE '%$search%' OR 
    user_nicename LIKE '%$search%' OR 
    user_email LIKE '%$search%' OR 
    user_url LIKE '%$search%'
    ) AND (
    wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'pie_address_3' AND 
    CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%$search%'
)
```

Notice that **AND** between the two parts.

There's the hook `pre_user_query` that fires after the `WP_User_Query` has been parsed, and before the query is executed, that passes the current `WP_User_Query` instance by reference. So we can intercept and change that **AND** into an **OR**, by including this code into our `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('pre_user_query', 'my_custom_users_search');
function my_custom_users_search( $args ) {
    $args->query_where = str_replace(') AND (', ') OR (', $args->query_where);
}
```

This would make the following query work:

```
$my_users = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'role'   => $role,
        'search' => '*' . $search . '*',
        'search_columns' => array(
            'user_login',
            'user_nicename',
            'user_email',
            'user_url',
            'display_name'
        ),
        'meta_key'     => 'pie_address_3',
        'meta_value'   => $search,
        'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
);
```

**Warning** : the previous action function can affect every `WP_User_Query` call!

In order to prevent that we can pass one dummy argument to the `WP_User_Query` function, and change the **AND** in **OR** only if that argument is passed. So this is the query with an `and2or` dummy argument:

```
$my_users = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'and2or' => 1,
        'role'   => $role,
        'search' => '*' . $search . '*',
        'search_columns' => array(
            'user_login',
            'user_nicename',
            'user_email',
            'user_url',
            'display_name'
        ),
        'meta_key'     => 'pie_address_3',
        'meta_value'   => $search,
        'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
);
```

And this is the action function:

```
add_action('pre_user_query', 'my_custom_users_search');
function my_custom_users_search( $args ) {
    if( isset( $args->query_vars['and2or'] ) )
        $args->query_where = str_replace(') AND (', ') OR (', $args->query_where);
}
```

---

### Old answer

This is the query that searches the serialized meta field (there's no need to split it, like you did on your update):

```
$my_users = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'role'         => $role,
        'meta_key'     => 'pie_address_3',
        'meta_value'   => $search,
        'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
);
```

With your query you were searching for `$search` even on the fields specified in the `search_columns` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'pie_address_3', 'meta_value' => $keyword, 'meta_compare' => 'LIKE' ) );


compare (string) - Operator to test. Possible values are '=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS', and 'NOT EXISTS'. Default value is '='.
```